# How to use QTextStream instead of QDataStream for load-save from QTableView?

Tags: c++, c, qt

I am newbie on QT, So when I try to load and save data from QTableView into txt files in linux using QDataStream I have a problem like this :

txt files contain data from tableview

[image]

All I want is the data in txt files easily to read, for example :
data1;data2
data3;data3

So, how to use QTextStream instead of QDataStream, because when I'm using QTextStream I can write output in txt just like this :

```
QFile ofile("/home/rizi/LearnQT/tes");
ofile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text);
QTextStream out(&ofile);
out << line+"\n";
```

Comment: Do you have code? I can't find the possbility to get an QIODevice from QTableView, or does your model?

Comment: Here's my code to print from QTableView into txt files :

`QFile file("/home/rizi/TableView/tes");

    if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
        QDataStream stream(&file);
        qint32 n(model->rowCount()), m(model->columnCount());
        stream << n << m;

        for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
            for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
                model->item(i,j)->write(stream);
        file.close();
    }`

I am using QStandardItemModel class to initate the model

Comment: I am just curios how to printout the data from QTableView using QTextStream so that the other user can read data in txt easily

Answer (score 0):

Each item in the model consists of more than a text. That's why write function requires a QDataStream instance. If saving only the text part of the data is ok for you then you can always:

```
qint32 n(model->rowCount()), m(model->columnCount()); 
stream << n << m; 
for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) 
for(int j=0; j<m; j++) 
stream << model->item(i,j)->text();
```

Comment: I've tried that before, but it didn't work so I changed the code to this :
.
.
.
`stream << model->item(i,j)->write(stream);`
I dont have any problem when write data from listview to txt, but tableview make me so mad.

Comment: stream << model->item(i,j)->write(stream); this is wrong. ->write(stream); part is not necessary